# About independent set in triangle free graphs

Tags: graphs

From Wikipedia :

> An independent set of $\sqrt{n}$ vertices in an $n$-vertex triangle-free graph is easy to find: either there is a vertex with more than $\sqrt{n}$ neighbors (in which case those neighbors are an independent set) or all vertices have less than $\sqrt{n}$ neighbors (in which case any maximal independent set must have at least $\sqrt{n}$ vertices)

Why does any maximal stable set have at least square root of $n$ vertices?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is that the graph is triangle free, so if $j$ and $k$ are both neighbours of $i$, then the edge $\{j,k\}$ is not in the graph.  This means that $N_i = \{j : \text{$i$ is a neighbour of $j$}\}$ is an independent set for any $i$.

The other fact being used is that a graph with $n$ vertices of maximum degree $\Delta$ has an independent set of size at least $\lfloor n/(\Delta+1)\rfloor$.

Comment: Can you please provide more details? And "has a set" and "every maximal" is different, no?

Comment: If the maximum degree is $\Delta$ than any independent set of size $t$ has at most $t\Delta$ neighbours.  Unless $t(\Delta +1) \ge n$, it's not maximal.

Comment: Okay, so if maximum degree is less than $\sqrt{n}$, then we have the bound. so here the triangle free property isn't used right? It is used only when saying that if a vertex has big neighborhood then take it as independent set. Am I right ?

Comment: Yes.  That's right.